# Script Manager ? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, before redirecting to another page i want to display message! after few seconds it redirect to that page. For that i write code in scriptmanager like this..

```
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "mess", "<script> window.setTimeout('window.location='http://www.stackoverflow.com'; ',4000) </script>", false);
```

but it is not redirecting , can you help me , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, will work

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType()
            , "mess", "<script> window.setTimeout(\"window.location='http://www.stackoverflow.com'\",4000) </script>", false);
```

*Note: Self tested solution*

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work:

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType() , "mess", " window.setTimeout(\"window.location.href='http://www.stackoverflowcom'\",4000) ", false);